# Profiling Azure in the Compute Emulator

Tags: c#, .net, azure, profiling, azure-compute-emulator

I'm having an issue where when I stop my Azure project and at random other times, it starts consuming massive amounts of memory and eventually uses all available RAM.

I can't seem to figure out how to profile my project in the compute emulator. I know I can profile in the cloud, but this issue primarily occurs in the emulator. I am aware the emulator doesn't accurately model the cloud, etc. etc., but I still want to use the emulator and so I need my project to work in it without chewing up my memory.

Can anyone let me know how to profile while running in the emulator?

Comment: When it starts doing that, can you just pause it and see what the heck it's doing?

Comment: Its difficult because the only reproducible way to cause it is to stop the emulator, which causes VS to detach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a different tool to profiler, for example, you could use the PerfView profiler that was just released:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2011/12/28/publication-of-the-perfview-performance-analysis-tool.aspx